# Jquery Validation in Spring

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

html forms can be validated through jquery plugin.so similarly i want to know any jquery plugin is available for validating spring forms.?

Thanks
Sree

Comment: what is the difference beween spring and html form ... use the same plugin as u use in html forms ...

Answer (score 1):

JSR 303 Bean Validation provides a comprehensive way to declare validation rules. Here is an link:

[Bean Validation and tips on twitter bootstrap](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/08/29/integrating-spring-mvc-with-jquery-for-validation-rules/)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for any Jquery plugin for validating spring forms.. first of all you need to know that jquery executes on client side which has no idea if the application is using spring or any other technology. with jquery you can only validate html forms on the client side which are the rendered from spring or any other web technology.
If you want more reliable validations in spring, see `@InitBinder` and vaildator interface.